# How can i download openGl for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, opengl

How can i download openGl for C#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536065/c-opengl might have helped, too.

Answer (score 1):

you might give this library a try: [SharpGL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/openGL/sharpgl.aspx).

Grz, Kris.

Comment: What you need is a OpenGL Binding, since OpenGL is usually provided as a C library. This answer is exactly what you need.

There's no OpenGL for C# more than just bindings.

Answer (score 1):

The [Tao](http://www.mono-project.com/Tao) project provides full OpenGL bindings (including extensions) for .NET (including C#).

Answer (score 0):

There is also ArcBall: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/openGL/arcball.aspx

There are also two parts to what you are looking for:
Arccball provides .NET bindings for OpenGL and will be used for the coding/implementation. At runtime, the calls to the OpenGL runtime are handled by opengl32.dll found in c:\windows\system32

One caveat is that you'll need a version match between opengl32.dll and whatever.NET library you use.