# Open Gl Usage in C++ or C#

Tags: c#, visual-c++, opengl, graphics

Hi my teacher has planned to do some programming teaching for us .He said that we have to chose `OpenGL` and use it to do graphics Stuff.

He has given each student liberty to select language of own choice.

I have experience with `c#` but class lectures would be in `Visual c++` some students have decided to go for `JAVA` Some for C++ now i want to ask is that

does `OpenGL` Supports `c#` ?

can we do all the things that are possible in c++ (so that i can translate the Class work in c#)

in which language is it easy to deal with OpenGl

basically I am not comfortable with c++.

Comment: That doesn't mean you shouldn't learn c++.

Comment: I can see several (correct) answers by googling 'OpenGL C#'. Do you think posting here is easier than making a single search request yourself?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean, does C# support OpenGL.  OpenGL is language agnostic, so you would not ask if it supported C#, but the other way around.

There are two frameworks i know of for C# opengl development,

- [Tao](http://sourceforge.net/projects/taoframework/)
- [OpenTK](http://opentk.sourceforge.net/)

However, you have to realize that with any framework, you end up learning the framework more than the actual technology its using.

Answer (score 2):

There are frameworks that have been built to do openGL in C#. I would recommend doing a google search and searching the site here before posting questions, as I found several answers immediately. [This one seems to be the most informative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536065/c-opengl), with several suggestions for openGL in C#. Also [this came up in a google search](http://csgl.sourceforge.net/) as well.

Comment: In regards to being able to do all the same things you can do in other languages like C++ I can't be sure since you're pretty much at the mercy of user-created frameworks, but I'm gonna go ahead and guess that you'll run into problems not as easily solved as if you were working in C++. I'd personally recommend going with C++. Trust me, the last thing you want to do is just stick with what is comfortable for you. You can't go wrong learning C++.

Answer (score 0):

Simply You have two options:

- Either Learn C++
- Or use [CsGL](http://csgl.sourceforge.net/) which is a wrapper for OpenGl