# OpenGL in Visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, opengl, visual-c#-express-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using OpenGl with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536065/using-opengl-with-c)

I'm working on a project for 3D game. I strictly need to use Visual C# with OpenGL in Visual Studio(WPF application).

I dont know anything about C# with OpenGL. Can anyone help me, tell me about which libraries I should use and what should I install to work with Visual C# using OpenGL in WPF application in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Open Toolkit](http://www.opentk.com/), it's a very well done C# OpenGL wrapper (and I believe OpenAL as well).

Answer (score 0):

First I would point out you can't use OpenGL with WPF per say. You have to use a "host container"(aka winforms container) in WPF

You must also use Direct3D 9 to properly use WPF in a game.
And you have to use Direct3D9Ex on Vista/7 and normal D3D9 on XP.

Also i'm starting a cross platform project for using D3D9/10 and GL under a common API.
Check out "http://code.google.com/p/reign-sdk/"... its waaay in the alpha state but you might find some stuff useful in there.

If you would like I get send you a demo how to use it in D3D10/9 or OpenGL.

Also look up OpenTK for good C# openGL API stuff.