# What advantages exist in C++ over C# when working with OpenGL

Tags: c#, c++, opengl

I am starting to get interested learning in OpenGL and I am trying to figure out what the best direction to go as far as which language to use in the learning process.  I am already very familiar with C# and from what I have read, I can utilize the Tao API to interface with OpenGL from C# code.  However, it also seems to me from what I'm reading that those who are really professional OpenGL developers are C++ programmers.

I'm curious what advantages C++ might have over C# when working with 3D graphics in OpenGL.  Any input would be great as I'm a complete newby at all this.

Comment: Vote for close. Google at "C# vs C++" and you'll find many many differences. Basically the complexity vs performance is number one. C++ can perform better yet if you have little experience in C++, the code you produce will probably perform worse than the C# equivalent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using OpenGl with C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536065/using-opengl-with-c)

Comment: While I'd normally vote to close "language X vs Y", I think this has merit for substantiated answers because it is more focused so ... leaving for others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using OpenGL via C# has some difficulties.

1. Getting an up-to-date SDK. Tao hasn't been updated since 2008. OpenTK hasn't had a stable release since June of 2010. OpenGL has had *two* version releases since June 2010. That's a lot of functionality you simply cannot access from C#. I don't know how stable OpenTK's nightlies are, but I generally don't trust nightlies. With C/C++, you can get whatever function pointers you want to load. With C#, you can only use what your toolkit provides.
2. Dealing with buffer objects can be quite painful in C#. Yes, there are ways to upload arrays of uniform values to buffer objects. But building interleaved vertex data, where different components have different types, is much more difficult in C#. In C and C++, you have direct access to memory. So it's easy to have a 3-vector of floats followed by a 4-vector of bytes, all stored in 16 bytes per vertex. It's rather more difficult in C#.
3. Graphics code is generally one of the more performance-critical areas of code. You will generally want the control that C++ affords if you're making a high-performance rendering application like a game. So many of C#'s nice features work against it here.

The only real advantage that using C# provides is that... it's C#. To the degree that you feel that advantages you, then it is an advantage.

Comment: Maybe using **C++/CLI** would be "the best of two worlds"?

Comment: @UweKeim: How? Sure, you get garbage collection (for the CLI part), and you can talk to the CLR standard libraries. But you get none of the nice language features of C#. And since the CLR standard libraries aren't terribly useful for a renderer, it's not that much of an advantage. The most you might use it for is interop with your renderer, but that would be written in straight C++. In which case, your renderer doesn't need to know or care that it's being called from the CLR.

Comment: hey Nicol i know this may be an old post and things get changed but its in the first search result in google so some points need to be cleared , 
one of them is : **can i create a general functions involve those complicated vectors in C++ and extract it in a dll file , and import that dll into C# project and call that dll -> functions and use them in c# to develop a game ? perhaps like Unity3D do maybe ?**

Answer (score 3):

The advantage most immediately relevant to you is the preponderance of tutorials using example code written in C, which C++ compilers will happily accept.

The most broadly applicable advantage is portability: C# is Microsoft's baby & support for that language on non-Microsoft platforms is sketchy at best. [Wikipedia currently claims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29#Versions) that the latest ISO standard for C# is 2.0, whereas Microsoft has released 4.0 and is already developing 5.0!

Comment: Just to update: According to MS BUILD 2014 the ISO for C# 5 is only a few months away and MS Roslyn opens the compiler. C# is really making progress in terms of cross platform.